# How to set max zoom in AndroidPdfViewer library, but not for double-click?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidpdfviewer

I'm using library for Android apps, that allows you to view pdf files (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2), however I've run into a problem. I needed to increase the maxZoom value. And I did it (up to the 20x). The zoom really zooms in better now, but it does it strangely, when I spread my fingers, to increase the zoom, it works up to a maximum value of 10x. To further increase the zoom to the value that I specified in the variable maxZoom(20x), need to use double-click

Here is my code:

```
private val pdfContainer by lazy {
    binding.pdfView
}

pdfContainer.maxZoom = 20f
pdfContainer.fromUri(Uri.parse(attachment.url))
        .enableSwipe(true)
        .swipeHorizontal(false)
        .enableDoubletap(true)
        .defaultPage(0)
        .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
        .fitEachPage(true)
        .password(null)
        .scrollHandle(null)
        .enableAntialiasing(true)
        .spacing(0)
        .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
        .load()
```